# Why the jQuery Selectable plugin doesn't work with a foreach generated list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-ui-selectable

I am currently working on an MVC project and implemented jQuery `Selectable` plugin. I have a string in my model which I have `Split()` as below in my view:

```
@{
    var size = Model.AvailableSizes.Split(',');
    foreach (var item in size)
    {
        <ol class="ui-selectable" id="selectable">
            <li class="ui-selectable">@item</li>
        </ol>
    }
}
```

Here is the static script defined in my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#selectable").selectable();
    });
</script>
```

The `selectable` jQuery plugin successfully generates the `<ol>`s for each item but I can only select the first item not the rest. What is the problem?

Comment: What an answer, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the `<ol>` *outside* the loop. Right now you're creating a N `ol` elements with a single `li` inside them, all with the same `id` which is both invalid HTML, and the cause of your problem.

Try this:

```
<ol class="ui-selectable" id="selectable">
    @{
        var size = Model.AvailableSizes.Split(',');
        foreach (var item in size)
        {
            <li class="ui-selectable">@item</li>
        }
    } 
</ol>
```