# JQuery doesn't work foreach loop button

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Hey guys I'm working on my new MVC app but...
The function I want to have with this code doesn't work.
When the user clicks on a Task, it has to appear in the paragraph. 
As you can see the function only works with the first table item.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
            var task = $('#taskDescription').val();
            $("#paragraph").append(task, "    <button>-</button></br>");
        });
    });
```

```css
.table-left {
            width: 30%;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        tbody {
            overflow: scroll;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-left">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Dienst</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        
            <tr>
                <td>hey</td>
                <td><button id="btnAdd">+</button></td>
                <input type="hidden" id="taskDescription"   value="hey" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>hi</td>
                <td><button id="btnAdd">+</button></td>
                <input type="hidden" id="taskDescription"   value="hi" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>hello</td>
                <td><button id="btnAdd">+</button></td>
                <input type="hidden" id="taskDescription"   value="hello" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>bye</td>
                <td><button id="btnAdd">+</button></td>
                <input type="hidden" id="taskDescription"   value="bye" />
            </tr>
       
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<p id="paragraph"></p>
```

Who knows what to do?
I read this post: [Why the jQuery Selectable plugin doesn't work with a foreach generated list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043635/why-the-jquery-selectable-plugin-doesnt-work-with-a-foreach-generated-list)

But it doesn't seem to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never have multiple elements with the same ID. An ID should **ALWAYS** be unique

Second, to get the value of the `taskDescription` that is associated with the clicked `btnAdd`, use `$(this).closest('tr').find('.taskDescription').val()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btnAdd").click(function() {
    var task = $(this).closest('tr').find('.taskDescription').val();
    $("#paragraph").append(task, "<button>-</button></br>");
  });
});
```

**Working example of your code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btnAdd").click(function() {
    var task = $(this).closest('tr').find('.taskDescription').val();
    $("#paragraph").append(task, "<button>-</button></br>");
  });
});
```

```css
.table-left {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}

tbody {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-left">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Dienst</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>hey</td>
        <td><button class="btnAdd">+</button></td>
        <input type="hidden" class="taskDescription" value="hey" />
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hi</td>
        <td><button class="btnAdd">+</button></td>
        <input type="hidden" class="taskDescription" value="hi" />
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td><button class="btnAdd">+</button></td>
        <input type="hidden" class="taskDescription" value="hello" />
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bye</td>
        <td><button class="btnAdd">+</button></td>
        <input type="hidden" class="taskDescription" value="bye" />
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<p id="paragraph"></p>
```

Comment: Oh ofcourse an id should be unique.. Thanks for your fast reply! I appreciate it

Comment: Yes it does! :)

Comment: @daphne If any of the answers helped you, you should consider marking one of them as answer, so others users can see what solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Change `ID` To `Class`
Change Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btnAdd").click(function () {

            var task = $(this).parent().next('input').val();
            $("#paragraph").append(task, "    <button>-</button></br>");
        });
    });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btnAdd").click(function () {
        
            var task = $(this).parent().next('input').val();
            $("#paragraph").append(task, "    <button>-</button></br>");
        });
    });
```

```css
.table-left {
            width: 30%;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        tbody {
            overflow: scroll;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-left">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Dienst</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        
            <tr>
                <td>hey</td>
                <td><button class="btnAdd">+</button></td>
                <input type="hidden" class="taskDescription"   value="hey" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>hi</td>
                <td><button class="btnAdd">+</button></td>
                <input type="hidden" class="taskDescription"   value="hi" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>hello</td>
                <td><button class="btnAdd">+</button></td>
                <input type="hidden" class="taskDescription"   value="hello" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>bye</td>
                <td><button class="btnAdd">+</button></td>
                <input type="hidden" class="taskDescription"   value="bye" />
            </tr>
       
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<p id="paragraph"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your button tag, change your id to class. and change **#** in your javascript to **.**

example :

```
<button type="button" id="blablabla"></button>, change to <button type="button" class="blablabla"> <br>
```

and in your javascript change :

```
$(#blablabla) to $(.blablabla)
```